# org.hibernate.QueryException: Legacy-style query parameters (`?`) are no longer supported; use JPA-style ordinal parameters (e.g., `?1`)

Tags: java, hibernate

currently I am trying to upgrade from hibernate 4 to hibernate5. But I am facing the issue of

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Legacy-style query parameters (`?`) are no longer supported; use JPA-style ordinal parameters (e.g., `?1`)
```

But I can't seem to find the '?' within my query.

Below are the codes for it

```
public List<CustConfigDTO> getCustConfigDetails() throws DAOException
    {
        try
        {
            String sectionQuery = "select * from cust_config";
            Query<?> query = getSession().createNativeQuery(sectionQuery, CustConfigDTO.class);
            return (List<CustConfigDTO>) query.list();
        }
        catch( Exception ex )
        {
            LOGGER.error( ex );
            throw new DAOException();
        }
    }
```

CustConfigDTO

```
public class CustConfigDTO implements java.io.Serializable
{

    private String config_for;
    private String config_value;
    private String config_description;

    public CustConfigDTO( String config_for,
                                   String config_value,
                               
                                   )
    {
        this.config_for = config_for;
        this.config_value = config_value;
        
    }

    public String getConfig_for()
    {
        return this.config_for;
    }

    public void setConfig_for( String config_for )
    {
        this.config_for = config_for;
    }

    public String getConfig_value()
    {
        return this.config_value;
    }

    public void setConfig_value( String config_value )
    {
        this.config_value = config_value;
    }
```

May I know what is required to change from my code?

Thank you

Comment: Which hibernate version are you using? Do you have any other queries?

Comment: hibernate-core 4.2.5.Final, and no I dont have other queries

Comment: You said you were upgrading to hibernate 5?

Comment: Hi Sorry, mistakes from my side, should be hibernate-core 5.4.33.Final

Comment: `SQLQuery` should be deprecated since 5.2. Try using `NativeQuery` like this: `Query<?> query = getSession().createNativeQuery(sectionQuery, CustConfigDTO.class);`

Comment: Hi, I have made the changes, but the error still exists. It is now pointing towards my DTO class, please check the newly added codes

Comment: If that is your ccomplete DTO class, you are 1. having a comma too much in the constructor `String config_value,`, 2. missing setter etc. for `config_description` and 3. should perhaps provide an empty constructor